# Capturing FormPanel exit

Tags: extjs, extjs3

We have a form panel which hosts an editable grid and a 'save' button.

```
PROJ.RWA = Ext.extend(Ext.form.FormPanel, 
{

    initcomponent:function(){
....
.....

var rwa_config = {
        ....... 
        tbar:rwa_tbar,
        items: [
            borr_grid, nonBorr_grid
            ],
        buttons: [{
                text: 'Save',
                handler:this.getValues
        },
        .....]
        .......             
    };

  Ext.apply(this, Ext.apply(this.initialConfig, rwa_config));
  PROJ.RWA.superclass.initComponent.call(this, rwa_config);
     }

}
```

This component is loaded from index.html
We need to ensure that the user gets a warning when he is navigating away from this panel,if there are unsaved changes on the grids.
If the grid is 'dirty' and 'save' is not yet clicked - we should pop-up a warning when the user is navigating away to some other page/panel.
How do  we do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a listener to the event `beforedestroy` or if it is closed normally then look into `beforeclose`.

It would look something like this:

```
listeners: {
    beforedestroy: function( panel, eOpts ){
        //check if there are unsaved changes (and show dialog or smoething)
    }
}
```

You can also `return false;` in a "before"-event to prevent the actual action.

Also look into the [beforedestroy doc](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.tree.Panel-event-beforedestroy).

Answer (score 0):

First: I guess that when save is clicked, you invoke an operation which returns success:true. Then, all records in the store are marked as "not dirty".

So, you would only have to check whether the grid has dirty records.

Depending on the exact ways how you can "leave" the grid, you can listen to one or more of the following events:

- `beforeclose`
- `beforedestroy`
- `beforehide`

In the handler, you would do sth like this:

```
onGridExit:function(grid) {
    if(grid.getStore().getUpdatedRecords().length>0) {
        Ext.MessageBox.alert('Unsaved changes','Would you like to save your changes?',function() {
            ...
        });
        return false;
    }
}
```